# In Constant Sorrow

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge, story, acrostic

I've decided to tell another story, though this one already exists. I'll give an overview and you'll have to tell me what story I am telling.

> Digging for punishment, our story begins; a story about, three unfortunate men.
>
> As fate would have it, three became four; one sold their soul, for fortune adored.
>
> Placed in the wrong, by time yes indeed; Nelson was there, when they were in need.
>
> Pitting the men against one another; then they met up, with Pete's older brother.
>
> Everett was married, his wife left his name; telling their kids, he was hit by a train.
>
> Remember Big Dan? He's quite the villain; leader of a cult, he's no stranger to killin'.
>
> Delmar is great, but not quite that bright; he thought Pete was a frog, turned overnight.
>
> Alas our story comes to a close, given a pardon, to the sheriff unknown.
>
> Nay, in the desk, the drawer on the top; the bottom of a river, thanks to the cops.

What story am I telling? How did you arrive at your answer? How does it relate to the title? Can you explain the acrostic?

Comment: I see you are doing more acrostic clues

Comment: I like acrostics and use them quite often in smaller riddles like this one.

Comment: I don't usually like riddles that require some very specific piece of trivia knowledge like this, but you can have a +1 for the great poetry style (rhyme, rhythm, and all).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the story of

> Oh Brother, Where Art Thou?

Explanation (Sorry, my memory of the film is a bit hazy)

Digging for punishment, our story begins; a story about, three unfortunate men.

> The three men are **Everett** McGill, **Pete** Hogwalop, and **Delmar** O'Donnel

As fate would have it, three became four; one sold their soul, for fortune adored.

> They meet Tommy Johnson who says he sold his soul for the ability to play guitar

Placed in the wrong, by time yes indeed; Nelson was there, when they were in need.

> They meet a robber named Baby Faced Nelson and the help him rob a bank when they are in need of money.

Pitting the men against one another; then they met up, with Pete's older brother.

> I think this might be referring to when they get into a fight because Everett lied about there being any treasure?

Everett was married, his wife left his name; telling their kids, he was hit by a train.

> If I remember right, Penny, Everett's wife told her kids that their dad was hit by a train so they wouldn't know he was a criminal.

Remember Big Dan? He's quite the villain; leader of a cult, he's no stranger to killin'.

> Big Dan was the leader of the KKK group that try to hang Tommy.

Delmar is great, but not quite that bright; he thought Pete was a frog, turned overnight.

> The trio are drugged by women and when Delmar wakes up he sees Pete's clothes on the ground with a frog in them. He thinks this means Pete was turned into a frog.

Alas our story comes to a close, given a pardon, to the sheriff unknown.

> When the trio are arrested and about to be hanged, they are "pardoned" by being saved by an impromptu (supernatural?) flood.

Nay, in the desk, the drawer on the top; the bottom of a river, thanks to the cops.

> I think this is referring to the ring that one of them finds in a desk drawer that doesn't actually belong to Everett's wife Penny.

Title

> The song that the trio records is called "Man of Constant Sorrow"

Acrostic

> Everett's favorite brand of pomade is called Dapper Dan. He's a Dapper Dan Man.

Comment: This was perfect! The only difference was the fact that they men were actually pardoned by the governor if I remember correctly, prior to the scene in which they are about to be hung.